# How to determine which of two Danish pronunciations is correct, or if both are?

Tags: pronunciation, danish

There is a common word in Danish for which I have encountered two pronunciations in my learning. Both of them sound fairly reasonable.

How do I figure out which of the pronunciations is correct and learn it, or figure out if both are and the variation is dialectical?

Comment: I would try to find an authoritative reference. Are there Danish dictionaries that provide IPA transcription?  Unfortunately, Dansk section of wiktionary doesn't provide those yet.

Comment: Related question Linguistics stack: [Are there any sources that provide accurate IPA transcriptions for Danish?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15032/are-there-any-sources-that-provide-accurate-ipa-transcriptions-for-danish)

Comment: Can you reveal what the word is?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I cannot, because it has been a while I do not remember it anymore. Also, questions about details of specific languages (like "how to pronounce a particular word) are not on topic on this SE website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked two Danish colleagues, who came to agreement about which pronunciation is correct, and found some instances of combined words where the other might also be used. The other pronunciation was not used independently. Since the colleagues are of different age and from different regions, I trust their judgement.

Answer (score 2):

This online Danish dictionary http://ordnet.dk/ddo/ordbog provides transcription and pronunciation. It's not IPA, it's their own variation of IPA. Transcription is described in detail [here](http://ordnet.dk/ddo/artiklernes-opbygning/udtale?set_language=da).

Answer (score 2):

I am native speaker of Danish, and I can tell you, that we pronounce differently depending on region. If you want anything concrete, go for what we call ["rigsdansk"](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigsdansk) (Standard Danish), and ask someone from [Sjaelland / Zeeland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zealand), since that dialect is closest to risdansk. To find the right pronunciation, would be difficult without knowing the word too.

Answer (score 1):

I´m living in Denmark, I don´t know if you also are. The best thing you can do is go to a Danish library and get a dictionary, they contain phonetic pronunciations as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to ask a native speaker. This is usually better than the dictionary method as in English for example the word "tomato" has two very distinct pronunciations.

Comment: A common reference for that is *[Let's Call the Whole Thing Off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Call_the_Whole_Thing_Off)* from the film *[Shall We Dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_We_Dance_(1937_film))* (1937). [A version on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIYS9EQWkXg).

Comment: *[Fred Astaire & Ginger Rogers - Let's Call the Whole Thing Off (1937)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRrw2hDjnl4)*